# Get all nodes in a tree

Tags: c#, c++

I have a little issue with the following program

```
internal IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>(string NodeName) where T : Root, new()
{
    var node = new T();
    return GetItems(NodeName, node).Cast<T>();
}

public IEnumerable<Root> GetItems(string NodeName, Root root)
{
    // do it
}
```

I would like to know how to change this into C++ code. This is what I have tried

```
template<class T>
list<T> GetItems(string NodeName)
{
    auto node = new T();
    return GetItems(NodeName, node);
}

list<Root> GetItems(string NodeName, Root root)
{
    // do it
}
```

Now I would like to mess it up a little

```
typedef shared_ptr<Root> ROOT_PTR;
class SmallRoot:public Root{};
list<ROOT_PTR> GetItems(string NodeName, ROOT_PTR rootPtr)
{
    //do something and return a list of share pointers      
}
```

then I am stuck at how to redesign the template `GetItems` to feed the `SmallRoot` classes

Comment: Oh yes C++, sorry about that, learn new thing now. It's C++, not C

Comment: Not clear what you are going to get. Where are you ging to decide if the object type is Root or SmallRoot ?  Your current GetItems(string NodeName) will not compile because type of "new T()" is pointer "T*"